# How to use optional parameters from decorated method in decorator method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function with an optional argument. How can I pass this argument into the decorator function?

```
    def decorator(self, func: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Callable[[Any, Any], Any]:
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            print(args) # does not contain the "optional_arg"
            print(kwargs) # does not contain the "optional_arg" either
            # How can I do something with the optional_arg in here?
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    @decorator
    def do_something(self, arg1: str, optional_arg="Hi") -> None:
        # do something
        pass

    do_something("arg1")
```

Comment: You could either require that the decorator is always used  with a call like `@decorator()` (making it actually a decorator factory function) or check if `func` parameter is really callable. If not, it is the optional argument and the `decorator` behaves as factory function only in this special case.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? How is your decorator supposed to work?

Comment: Basically I need to call other methods inside my decorator function which will need both `arg1` and `optional_arg`. I'm trying to pass in both without impacting other callers of `do_something`

Comment: Again, can you be more concrete? You *know the names of these parameters ahead of time*? It seems like your decorator is supposed to work with a specific function with a specific signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator can introspect the function it wraps to get its signature, and using the signature, you can combine the passed arguments with the defaults to produce the final version of the bound arguments without calling the function, allowing them to be used to call other functions that aren't aware of the defaults.

```
import inspect  # At top of file

def decorator(self, func: Callable[[Any], Any], ) -> Callable[[Any, Any], Any]:
    # For performance, extract the signature at decoration time, not on every call
    sig = inspect.signature(func)

    def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)  # Binds any arguments passed, raises a TypeError if required arguments missing, just like calling func without them would
        bound.apply_defaults()   # Computes missing arguments from defaults in signature
        print(bound.args)    # Will include optional_arg when final argument can be passed positionally, like in this case
        print(bound.kwargs)  # Since keyword arguments not *needed* here (no arguments must be skipped on way to a later argument), this is empty

        # If you want to call some other function here with a known matching prototype, that doesn't know the defaults of func, you can do:
        other_func(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)

        # Func knows its defaults, so it can use original args/kwargs
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

        # But the process of binding and resolving defaults is work you've already done,
        # and it could reduce the use of keyword arguments (which are more expensive to pass)
        # so you could reuse bound here instead:
        return func(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)

    return wrapper

@decorator
def do_something(self, arg1: str, optional_arg="Hi") -> None:
    # do something
    pass
```

Note that `do_something("arg1")` will not work here, nor will your decorator work (because both expect a `self` argument, which neither is receiving, presumably because your real code involves classes with methods). Presumably this should be called on an instance of some class you've omitted, though it's impossible for both the decorator and the instance to be defined in the *same* class with the decorator receiving `self` (it doesn't make any sense). If you drop the `self` argument from *both* of them, and define them outside any class, `do_something("forarg1")` will work as expected, with your `print` showing `bound.args` being a `tuple` containing `"forarg1"`, and `"Hi"`, with `bound.args` being the empty `dict` (since it could bind the optional argument in order positionally without relying on keyword arguments).

Just to show it works, you can [try a version without `self` online here](https://tio.run/##ZVFNa4QwEL3nVwz2orIrlN6ELS297Kl/YCkSNbqhcRKSyOKvt2P8WKVzmJC8ee/xJmbwd41v4yg7o60Hic6IyjPWWN2BH4zEFhYsZawWDdSi0pZ7beOmxyqHL64UL5W43T5x@DnB3BM4vx@hFZl6zoDKyRYuq2VGN@S@tyLoJiyMTIYPy40RNk65bV0OQSpNfx/bNXjROatOVeoea9ImzayUWM/cJy05TmZkoIaCzHivvIufsLESfbwMHYh7ZBXdQCsoCMIU5L81200s2Rj72NY6L1kXTnfC32n/MdFec3DenkAbLzVyVdDbJbrKKGT/1ijm8C/EhI0Zngx3jn5uLxg1ZEWiUTKOfw), which shows the output I described above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass it to the decorator explicitly.

If you follow through to the call to the decorated function, you will see that the optional value is set to the default (`="Hi"`) when you omit it from the call to `do_function("arg1")`, and it will be set to whatever value if you include it.

The reason this works is that `args` and `kwargs` does not contain the default value for `optional_arg`, but `func` does.

Full example code:

```py
from typing import *

def decorator(func: Callable[[Any], Any]) -> Callable[[Any, Any], Any]:
    def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        print(args)  # does not contain the "optional_arg"
        print(kwargs)  # does not contain the "optional_arg"
        
        return func(*args, **kwargs)  # func DOES contain "optional_arg"

    return wrapper

@decorator
def do_something(arg1: str, optional_arg="Hi") -> None:
    print("Result:", (arg1, optional_arg))

do_something("arg1")
print("====")
do_something("arg1", "optional_arg")
```

Output:

```
('arg1',)
{}
Result: ('arg1', 'Hi')
====
('arg1', 'optional_arg')
{}
Result: ('arg1', 'optional_arg')
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I specifically need to do with some with optional_arg in my decorator

Comment: @Zigzagoon you should probably clarify, you want to use that argument in `wrapper`